# HSQL - set default value as current timestamp for varchar column

Tags: sql, timestamp, hsqldb, default-value

Is there a way to set the default value of a varchar column to the current date?

Like using

```
date varchar(255) default convert(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, SQL_VARCHAR)
```

I've been going around trying some solutions for the past few hours. None worked. I get an error (unexpected token) every time.
Why don't I use datetime you may ask? But it's not my decision to make unfortunately.

Comment: (－‸ლ) Date as string.  Do not do it :)

Comment: This is not possible. HSQLDB does not allow to use a function for a default value. Why don't you store this as a real timestamp value and create view that returns the timestamp formatted in the way you need it?

Comment: I know. But for some reason, my company need it to be in varchar. Would have been easier in datetime I agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, by default HSQLDB does not allow function calls in the DEFAULT CLAUSE. It is also not a good idea to store dates in a VARCHAR column.

But functions are allowed in the ORA syntax compatibility mode. You can set this mode with:

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE
```